# How can I use luaXML with LUA 5.3

Tags: lua, luarocks, luaxml

I'm gonna work with LUA and my goal is to make running a script that uses lausocket and luaXML to do its task.

I'm using Windows 2012 Server 64bit, I already have the LUA compiler in my IBM IDOL 11 folder in two files:

- lua53.exe
- lua53.dll

The problem is that I didn't have any lua header directory to point to install the luarocks, So I grabbed the header direcotry from official LUA 5.3.4. all went ok, I installed laurocks 2.4.4 for Windows on the system and I successfully installed luasocket with the command

```
c:\luarocks install luasocket
```

The problems arose with luaXML.

with the command

```
c:\luarocks install luaxml
```

I get the error

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/luaxml-101012-1.src.rock
C:\Program_Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -O2 -c -o LuaXML_lib.o -IC:/Program Files (x86)/lua/5.3/include LuaXML_lib.c
LuaXML_lib.c: In function 'Xml_eval':
LuaXML_lib.c:284:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lua_objlen'; did you mean 'lua_len'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int newIndex=lua_objlen(L,-1)+1;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
                 lua_len
LuaXML_lib.c: In function 'luaopen_LuaXML_lib':
LuaXML_lib.c:415:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'luaL_register'; did you mean 'lua_register'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  luaL_register(L, "xml", funcs);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  lua_register
C:\Program_Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -shared -o LuaXML_lib.dll LuaXML_lib.o C:/MF_IDOLServer/cfs/lua_ide_files/bin/lua53_win64/lua53.dll -lm
LuaXML_lib.o:LuaXML_lib.c:(.text+0xd23): undefined reference to `lua_objlen'
LuaXML_lib.o:LuaXML_lib.c:(.text+0xf20): undefined reference to `lua_objlen'
LuaXML_lib.o:LuaXML_lib.c:(.text+0x1103): undefined reference to `luaL_register'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module LuaXML_lib.dll
```

I googled this error and I found that it is due to the not compatibility between the luaXML lib and lua 5.3, luaxml-101012-1 and luaxml-101012-2 only support lua 5.1 but not lua 5.3.

So I tried to use the latest release of the luaxml library:

```
luarocks install luaxml 130610-1
```

with the result:

```
Error: luaxml 130610-1 supports only Lua 5.2 but not Lua 5.3.
```

how can I go on in order to install luaXML on the system and run the .lua script I have?

Thank you for all for any advice!

Comment: I share the same "quest" !
I found that a lua 5.3 compatible version of luaxml is part of the CTAN repository and maintained by Michal Hoftich. [https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luaxml]
However, I am still trying to make it work  !

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution user1771398; finally I made it work by downloading the the zip of luaXML 130610, changing its rockspec modifying the compatibility value writing  "> 5.2" and the addressing value writing to take the zip file avoiding its download from the repository. In this way the compilation was successfully done. I know it is only a workaround waiting for a stable luaXML version that supports LUA 5.3.

Comment: Do you use luaxml with lua standalone or within LuaTex ? I am stuck with a dependency with LuaTex with an error with "unicode.utf8.char" and I don't know how to get the library.

Comment: This has now been fixed by the developper of luaxml.